# How to solve this that tabs in viewpager overlay when screen rotation?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Here, I have a Activity with a ViewPager, it has 4 tabs, here is the activity screen shot link.

[image: 1]

Here is the screen shot for tab 4, when the screen is vertical.
when the activity is opened, I switch to the fourth tab, and then switch to the second, rotate the screen, part of the fourth tab will overlay on the second tab, but when switch to the first and the third, it won't happen,
the picture is as following:

**tab 4:**

[image: 2]

**tab 1:**

[image: 3]

**tab 2:**

[image: 4]

How could I have solved this problem?

following  is the adapter of viewpager:

```
public class MainPageFragmentPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

SparseArray<Fragment> fragmentSparseArray = new SparseArray<Fragment>();

private Fragment currentSelectedFragment;

public MainPageFragmentPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (fragmentSparseArray.get(position) == null) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new NewHomePageFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new NewDiscoverFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new NewUserMessageFragment();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new NewUserDetailFragment();
        }
        fragmentSparseArray.put(position, fragment);
    }
    currentSelectedFragment = fragmentSparseArray.get(position);
    return currentSelectedFragment;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 4;
}

public Fragment getCurrentSelectedFragment() {
    return currentSelectedFragment;
}

}
```

Any code you want to see please comment below.

Comment: I found the problem is about the method named destroyItem,when I overwrite this method it will be OK,but it will report a exception that id repeat

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I have embedded your images in the question for you. Please use the [edit] button to correct the text so that your question is described as you wanted. I have to guess where you wanted the images as it was not very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, You do not destroyItem when pager is not visible,so it will still in memory,and redraw it

Answer (score 0):

Please manage screen orientation through onConfigurationChanged Android method.